# Critical error on shop page on my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, woocommerce

I've been dealing with this problem since last night and I still couldn't solve the problem. And I'm about to go crazy, I couldn't understand what exactly caused the problem.

The problem is; when I click on the shop page in Woocommerce, it throws me to a page as seen in the picture and

Error I got; Show:There has been a critical error on this website.
Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.

The steps I took for the solution;
I disabled all the plugins on my wordpress site and activated them one by one

2. I have two shop pages, I tried 2 of them in woocommerce and both gave the same error.
   I changed one of the
   3."shop" page "shops" I changed it to.  defined it again in woocommerce but the result is still the same

My System  information ;

1. I have a on Google cloud Platform.
2. *WordPress with NGINX and SSL packaged by Bitnami 5.8.1-36*
3. wordpress version :Current version: 5.8.2
4. Woocommerce Version : Version 5.9.0 |

Thank you in advance for your valuable answers. I hope you can help me solve my problem...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Friends, the source of the problem was the error I got because my theme was not updated due to the update received by wordpress. The theme was updated and the problem was solved.

my problem was not related to this, but I tried them too, just because it is solved, there is no such thing as it will be solved in the same way for you, of course, but adding the code below to your wp.config file. maybe it can solve your problem.

/**
shope page errors  attempt
*/
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false`enter code here` );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This improvement above came from me. The addition of the `WP_DEBUG` code does not "solve your problem", it is there to write a logfile from which one can read error information.